# Loop array in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, loops

I'm sorry if the subject has already been asked, but i can't seem to find my answer.

Here is a pseudo-code i would like to apply :

```
Select id from session;
```

Then, for each id selected (so an array must be returned i think), i would like to calculate something. Here, in pseudo code :

```
For each id do operation ...
```

I'm again sorry if the topic has already been asked. Can anyone, anyway, have the patience to answer me please ?

Comment: Do you want to select it like `Select calculation(id)` ? It's rather unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: yes, it is as you said... i'm sorry if i'm not quite clear ... actually, i would lile to do something like this :                                                                                for each id do select calculation(id) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it backwards. In SQL everything works with sets. So just:

```
SELECT id, calculation(id)
FROM session;
```

---

To do it the way you describe:

Create the array with `array_agg`:

```
Select array_agg(id) from session;
```

`unnest` the array using an (implicit) lateral query:

```
SELECT calculation(array_value)
FROM my_table mt
CROSS JOIN unnest(mt.array_column) mt_ac(array_value)
```

`mt_ac(array_value)` is an *alias* for the output of the `unnest`, saying "I want to refer to the virtual table created by the `unnest` as `mt_ac`, and the single column it produces should be named `array_value`"

---

On old PostgreSQL versions you can't do it this way, and have to put the `unnest` in the `SELECT` clause instead, then use it as a subquery in `FROM`.

Comment: thank you for your answer ... say, how do i put all of my id in an array ?       i mean : when u say  Select calculation(array_value), how do i get this array_value of id ? can i put instead "select id from my_table" ?

Comment: Post a new question for a new topic please. You can link back to this one for context if it's relevant. Providing *sample data* (preferably in the form of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) is helpful.

Comment: Oh, hang on, I think I just saw the problem. You're thinking you need an array but you don't. Editing. Done, see top of post.